# Zend_Forms and decorators in ZF - Displaying label, input and errors in one container

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element, zend-decorators

pretty much ripping my hair out over how badly designed the decorators are in Zend Framework.
I've spent a lot of today and a few other days trying to figure out how to do something that should be a simple frontend task.

Zend_Forms and decorators in my opinion are the worst part of ZF as backend and frontend are not properly seperated. Why is the form class dictating how the HTML should be printed?

All I'm looking for, is something `simple` like:

```
<div class="labeledField">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
</div>
<div class="labeledField">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
</div>
```

The reason I want it like this is because I want the label to sit on top of the field like:

```
[Username       ]
[Password       ]
```

This way I can make the label slightly fade when the input is selected but still remain when the input is selected. Using JS the label is hidden when the input box contains anything. This functionality exists on the Apple shopping cart.

I love the validation parts of Zend_form and I would love how it can be placed in the frontend if backend code wasn't dictating how the HTML looks.

In my opinion it should either take a template (from a frontender with access to the /views/ folder or I should be able to do something like:

```
<div class="labeledField">
    <?php
    echo $this->form->username->getLabel();
    echo $this->form->username->getElement();
    $errors = $this->form->username->getErrors();
    if (sizeof($errors) > 0) {
        ?>
        <div class="errors">
        <?php
        foreach($errors as $error) {
            ?>
            <li><?php echo $error ?></li>
            <?php
        } 
        ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

But then the templating would allow me to just echo $this->form and have it use the format as above for fields I want to.

Comment: Yeah, Zend_Form is my least favorite component. My advice: ditch Zend_Form and just use the validator classes to validate input from your own hand-coded forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No question about it, decorators can take some getting used to. Let me address/answer some of your issues/questions:

> pretty much ripping my hair out over how badly designed the decorators are in Zend Framework. I've spent a lot of today and a few other days trying to figure out how to do something that should be a simple frontend task.

Yep, it's a miracle I have any hair left at all.

> Zend_Forms and decorators in my opinion are the worst part of ZF as backend and frontend are not properly separated. Why is the form class dictating how the HTML should be printed?

I agree with you here that how the form is to be rendered is a presentation issue, so it's probably more view-related. If you really wanted to separate the concerns, you could create your forms undecorated and then add decorators in your view-script, perhaps using some custom view-helpers. This makes the most sense to me, though I confess I have never bothered to do it.

For examples of a standalone class that sets decorators on a separate form, check out [EasyBib_Form_Decorator](https://github.com/easybib/EasyBib_Form_Decorator) and [Using Zend_Form without Zend Framework MVC](http://www.tibobeijen.nl/blog/2009/12/07/using-zend_form-without-zend-framework-mvc/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+tbnl+%28TBNL%29)

> In my opinion it should either take a template (from a frontender with access to the /views/ folder or I should be able to do something like:

You pretty much do have that functionality using the [ViewScript decorator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardDecorators.html#zend.form.standardDecorators.viewScript).

```
$form->setDecorators(array(
    array('ViewScript', array(                      // note case
        'viewScript' => '_partials/forms/my.phtml', // note case
)));
```

That said, your desired markup is relatively straightforward using standard decorators:

```
// not tested, but should be pretty close
$element->setDecorators(array(
   'ViewHelper',
   'Label',
   'Errors',
   array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'div', 'attribs' => array('class' => 'labeledField'))),
));
```

Of course, any special styling or client-side manipulation of the form - for example, the Apple cart effect you cite - can be layered on to this markup on the client-side.

Comment: Thanks for all of the information, it's the best I've heard so far. I still don't get the logic of how its pieced together though :D Your example works out of the box but attempting to use it for something slightly different just doesn't work and I'm scratching my head wondering how I'm supposed to think about it logically. Trying to get <div>Checkbox Label</div>

Comment: I have this: 

    `$checkboxDecorator = array(
      'ViewHelper',
      'Label', 
      'Errors',
      array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'checkbox')),
      array('label', array('placement', 'APPEND'))
     );`

But then the label is outside of the container... so I'd think you need to get that piece done before you wrap it... they're both wrapped but its not appended! Not quite sure how to look at it

Comment: Ok now that HAS to be a bug... I fixed it by changing the 'label' to 'Label'... but the following works with both a lowercase and uppercase: `$checkboxDecorator = array(
      'ViewHelper',
      array('label', array('placement' => 'APPEND'))
     );`

Comment: Sorry for replying so much but for anyone else coming across the same issue... the reason it doesn't work is because I'm mixing both 'Label' and 'label'. It works if they're both label or Label.
Gonna use the viewscript decorators anyway :) Thanks so much

Comment: Yeah, the short-syntax for specifying decorators - with all its nested arrays - can be pretty confusing. The 'Label vs label' business you are hitting is because these standard decorators are named to match the filename as they appear in the folder Zend/Form/Decorator (the default plugin loader for form elements comes out of the box configured with a mapping of the prefix Zend_Form_Decorator_ to that folder). Glad that you managed to figure it all out. Cheers!